# Hibernate Could not execute query Invalid value for getInt()

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have two MYSQL Tables : Account and User. One user can have many accounts so it's a one to many relationship.
Account has the columns : id, user, title, bank, type. It also has one entry :

> 1 user1 Checking BankName Debit

User has the columns : id, first, last, username, password. It has one entry as well :

> 1 John Doe user1 hunter2

I've made the class and hibernate mapping for each:

```
public class Account {

    private int id;
    private User user;
    private String title;
    private String bank;
    private String type;
    private double amount;

    public Account() {
    }

    public Account(User usr, String nm, String bnk, String typ) {
         this.user = usr;
        this.name = ttl;
        this.bank = bnk;
        this.type = typ;
    }
    //getters and setters
 }
```

Here's my mapping

```
<class name="com.package.dao.beans.Account" table="budgeting.ACCOUNT">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the account detail.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="user" class="com.package.dao.beans.User"
        column="user" unique="true" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="title" column="title" type="string" />
    <property name="bank" column="bank" type="string" />
    <property name="type" column="type" type="string" />

</class>
```

Here's my User class

import java.util.Set;

```
public class User {
private int id;
private String first;
private String last;
private String username;
private String password;

public User() {
};

public User(String fName, String lName, String uName, String pass) {
    this.first = fName;
    this.last = lName;
    this.username = uName;
    this.password = pass;
};
//getters and setters
}
```

And accounts' mapping

```
    <class name="com.package.dao.beans.User" table="budgeting.users">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the account detail.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="first" column="first" type="string" />
    <property name="last" column="last" type="string" />
    <property name="username" column="username" type="string" />
    <property name="password" column="password" type="string" />
</class>
```

When I run some code to print out all the accounts (just one),

```
public class ManageAccount {
private static SessionFactory factory;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List accounts = session.createQuery("FROM Account").list();
        for (Iterator iterator = accounts.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Account acc = (Account) iterator.next();
            // System.out.print("First Name: " + acc.getUser().getFirst());
            System.out.print("  Last Name: " + acc.getName());
            System.out.println("  Salary: " + acc.getType());
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'user1'
```

I don't see why it would be using getInt(), it's clearly a String or Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the following mapping

```
<many-to-one name="user" class="com.package.dao.beans.User"
        column="user" unique="true" not-null="true"/>
```

What it actually says is that the Account entity is mapped as the many part of a relationship to one User using as a foreign key the column user of the Account table. 
But User's primary key is int

```
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
```

while the user column in Account as inferred from your sample data clearly is the username (i.e. string).

What you can do is use the User id (int) as a foreign key in the Account table, not the username

Comment: Your assessment is incorrect. In many-to-one the name value must match the corresponding field name in the Java class, which it does. The column value will be the column name in the database. Hibernate will automatically use primary keys as the foreign key association.

Comment: You are referring to JPA annotations. Here it is hibernate xml configuration

Comment: At my work we are using XML as well since we are limited to the version of Hibernate we can use. My statement was referring to XML configurations. You need to target the Java field name so Hibernate knows how to create each object and connect them correctly. And by default Hibernate connects tables on primary keys.

Comment: Correct. However I cannot still see what's wrong with my assessment. Given column names in Account table are : id, user, title, bank, type and corresponding values : 1 user1 Checking BankName Debit , which clearly shows that column user is string. And hibernate tries to associate with int PK

Comment: Sorry you are correct. It does look like it is joining on the username column instead of the id column. In our code Hibernate always joins on the primary key. Maybe there is something he did that is causing the issue.

Comment: But it does join to the PK here too. Only the PK is a surrogate id field, not username.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when joining tables in a query. Hibernate could not properly map the columns to the correct fields because I had duplicate names. In your Java classes it is ok, but you should make sure each column name is unique, especially if you are going to join tables. Here is what I would do:

```
<class name="com.package.dao.beans.Account" table="budgeting.ACCOUNT">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the account detail.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="account_id"> // ***** change here
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="user" class="com.package.dao.beans.User"
        column="account_user_id" unique="true" not-null="true"/> // ***** change here
    <property name="title" column="title" type="string" />
    <property name="bank" column="bank" type="string" />
    <property name="type" column="type" type="string" />

</class>

<class name="com.package.dao.beans.User" table="budgeting.users">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the account detail.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="user_id">  // ***** change here
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="first" column="first" type="string" />
    <property name="last" column="last" type="string" />
    <property name="username" column="username" type="string" />
    <property name="password" column="password" type="string" />
</class>
```